# Passing array of images to compute shader

Tags: compute-shader, webgl2

I am currently working on a project using the draft for Compute shaders in WebGL 2.0. [[draft]](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0-compute/).
Nevertheless I do not think that my question is WebGL specific but more an OpenGL problem. The goal build a pyramid of images to be used in a compute shader. Each level should be a squares of 2^(n-level) values (down to 1x1) and contain simple integer/float values...

I already have the values needed for this pyramid, stored in different
OpenGL Images all with their according sizes. My question is: how would you pass my image array to a compute shader. I have no problem in restricting the amount of images passed to lets say 14 or 16... but it needs to be at-least 12. If there is a mechanism to store the images in a Texture and than use `textureLod` that would solve the problem, but I could not get my head around how to do that with Images.

Thank you for your help, and I am pretty sure there should be an obvious way how to do that, but I am relatively new to OpenGL in general.

Comment: As mentioned I am using WebGL proposal extension to WebGL2 which provides support for Compute Shaders. As also said, the question is not purely WebGL related.

Comment: Can't you just use `texelFetch` in your shaders? `texelFetch(sampler, intTextureCoodinate, intMipLevel)`

Answer (score 1):

Passing in a "pyramid of images" is a normal thing to do in WebGL. They are called a mipmap.

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 0, gl.R32F, 128, 128, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some128x128FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 1, gl.R32F, 64, 64, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some64x64FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 2, gl.R32F, 32, 32, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some32x32FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 3, gl.R32F, 16, 16, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some16x16FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 4, gl.R32F, 8, 8, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some8x8FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 5, gl.R32F, 4, 4, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some4x4FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 6, gl.R32F, 2, 2, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some2x2FloatData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXUTRE_2D, 7, gl.R32F, 1, 1, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, some1x1FloatData);
```

The number in the 2nd column is the mip level, followed by the internal format, followed by the width and height of the mip level.

You can access any individual texel from  a shader with `texelFetch(someSampler, integerTexelCoord, mipLevel)` as in

```
uniform sampler2D someSampler;

...

   ivec2 texelCoord = ivec2(17, 12);  
   int mipLevel = 2;
   float r = texelFetch(someSampler, texelCoord, mipLevel).r;
```

But you said you need 12, 14, or 16 levels. 16 levels is 2(16-1) or 32768x32768. That's a 1.3 gig of memory so you'll need a GPU with enough space and you'll have to pray the browser lets you use 1.3 gig of memory.

You can save some memory by allocating your texture with `texStorage2D` and then uploading data with `texSubImage2D`.

You mentioned using images. If by that you mean `<img>` tags or `Image` well you can't get Float or Integer data from those. They are generally 8 bit per channel values.

Or course rather than using mip levels you could also arrange your data into a texture atlas

Comment: That sounds alot like what I want to achieve, the only caveat right now is that I still do not know how to get the data of the glImages into float data arrays...

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to explain what i am trying to do: my goal is to build a density pyramid with n levels for a couple of points in 2d.. similar to quadtrees i want to count the number of points in each quadrant. And i already did that in an earlier compute shader: for every level the sum of the underlying 4 quadrants is built and stored in an glImage of type R32F... now i want to pass this whole pyramid to a different compute shader